# What does the started keyword do in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have created a table that has a column with the name `started` of type `datetime`. I was very surprised to see this turn blue when I copied my select statement into management studio. When looking at the list of reserved words for SQL in the Microsoft documentation [(see here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), I cannot find the word `started`.

What is it? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very old SSMS problem.

I'm afraid M$ doesn't care about some tokens treated as keywords.

See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330118).

Comment: +1 Thanks. This is useful, submitted by Aaron Bertrand, I've seen him on SO. Looks like MS are still looking at it 4 years after it was submitted :P

Comment: @Jack Pettinger: as usual :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. There is no keyword exist with the name `started`.

I was able to create table

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11b8e)**

Comment: but `started` appears in blue in ssms, which would suggest it is